# Registering for notification causes error on mac

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, push-notification, provisioning-profile

I am doing something like this:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    // Insert code here to initialize your application

    NSApplication *application = [aNotification object];
    NSRemoteNotificationType myTypes = NSRemoteNotificationTypeBadge;
    [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:myTypes];
}

//Successful
-(void)application:(NSApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken{
    NSLog(@"device token: %@", deviceToken);
}
//Failure to register
-(void)application:(NSApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error{
    NSLog(@"ERROR: %@\nError object: %@", [error localizedDescription], error);
}
```

And I am getting the following error:

```
2014-06-14 20:47:13.656 RajamManagerStation[1878:303] ERROR: The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error 1.)
Error object: Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=1 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error 1.)" (kCFHostErrorHostNotFound / kCFStreamErrorSOCKSSubDomainVersionCode / kCFStreamErrorSOCKS5BadResponseAddr / kCFStreamErrorDomainPOSIX / evtNotEnb / siInitSDTblErr / kUSBPending / dsBusError / kStatusIsError / kOTSerialSwOverRunErr / cdevResErr / EPERM:  / Error code is the version of SOCKS which the server wishes to use /  / POSIX errno; interpret using <sys/errno.h>  / event not enabled at PostEvent / slot int dispatch table could not be initialized. /  / bus error /  /  / Couldn't get a needed resource; alert / Operation not permitted)
```

I dont understand what I can do to fix it.

I was watching the WWDC apple video in 2011 relating to push notifications, and there was a slide in there that showed:
[image]

It tells me that if the error delegate callback is called that I should check my privisioning profile for entitlements.

I have done everything I possiby could to get things working but I am receiving this error still. What can I do to fix it?

**UPDATE 1** - Just to affirm that I have enabled push notification services in the enabled services list.

[image]

**UPDATE 2** - Affirming that push notifications is there on the provisioning profile

[image]

Comment: Could you describe what you've actually done in "I have done everything"? I wonder if provisioning profile you use has "Push Notifications" in the Enabled Services list (check via developer.apple.com).

Comment: @Andrey Yes Andrey, it does! Are you online atm buddy?

Comment: If you happen to be online, I can quickly share my screen with you using an easy method so that you could confirm what I've done! I keep deleting my profiles, and recreating them, including the development push notification certificate too, and enabling "push notifications" in the services list. I always do this via the `developer.apple.com` site too. Can we screenshare for a moment if thats ok with you @Andrey?

Comment: @Andrey, I've updated the post to address the Enabled Services question. What other things can I look at?

Comment: unfortunately I don't have experience with making it work, I happened to read on the steps required for that before and since that is a multistep procedure, I wondered if you completed it in full, which probably you did. I would still check with https://parse.com/tutorials/ios-push-notifications - topic entitled "Creating the Provisioning Profile" - where it is described that a provisioning profile will have to be created with the push-enabled App ID, registered device should be added to the profile. It should then be installed into device.

Comment: Before downloading provisioning profile I'd check it mentions push service, e.g. `"Enabled Services: Push Notifications, ..."`

Comment: @Andrey, it does indeed say that. I've updated the post to address this. I'm in development mode, trying to test out push notifications, if I am just able to register myself for notifications and get a device token to begin with instead of getting this gross error, then it would help! What can we do mate?

Comment: @Pavan did you ever find a solution to this? I am coming across the same problem. Although it only happens when I archive the application and try to run it outside of Xcode.

Comment: @nvd90 hey, no I am still stuck with this current problem. Its frustrating. If you do happen to get it working, please let me know. In fact the best thing would be to post an answer of what you have so far so that we can work it out together. Even better would be to create a new project and try the process again with a blank project with push notifications enabled and see if it works with the new project, records your steps as you go along with screenshots. Youre actually very close if youve been able to run your program locally. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Hi @Pavan, you've found the solution to this problem yet? I have same problem.

Comment: Hey @cuGoku, I'm still working on the project. *sighs*, And no, not yet. Let me know what you find.

Comment: @Pavan same issue here, any guess how to fix it?

Comment: just found how to fix, go to target -> capabilities and make sure you've all your entitlements checked

Answer (score 1):

**Switch on the Push Notifications capability for your target.** In XCode, go to Target -> Capabilities, and ensure "Push Notifications" is set to ON:

[image: Capabilities tab showing Push Notifications set to ON]

(Thanks to @mateusmaso's comment for this solution!)